# ImageMagick Convert: how to add alpha shadows upon RGB image?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Given a RGB image :

[image]

Given a grey scale, opacity 0% to opacity 100% black image:

[image]

**How to add the alpha shadows upon the RGB image using a shell command ?** (preferemce for  ImageMagick Convert)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would compose the images using the [*Multiply*](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#multiply) operator. The command

```
convert src.png overlay.png -compose Multiply -geometry 948x630 -composite out.png
```

produces:

[image]

Comment: Given that both image have similar dimensions, is `-geometry 948x630` needed ?

Comment: @Hugoplz They didn't have the same dimension when I downloaded them. If they have the same dimension the `-geometry` option is unnecessary.

Comment: Oh, I may have upload one of the image AFTER resizing it, my apologizes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the example "[Using Masks with Images](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#masks)" covers this. Simply disable the alpha channel, and copy over the second image as opacity composite. Add `-negate` option to invert the 0% ~ 100% opacity -- if needed.

```
 convert map_image.png elevation_mask.png \
         -alpha Off -compose CopyOpacity -composite \
         out.png
```

[image: alpha mask]